# Is it possible to avoid SuperViews when hitTesting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, frame, hittest

Basically, I want to be able to click all the Subviews in the Image below...

I want to be able to tap the Subviews of View B but View A is in the way even though View A Subviews are not blocking the views below. Is this possible? In other words I want to be able to tap through the transparent parts of a view even though its frame/bounds cover that area. View B is under View A in a ScrollView.

thanks,
austin

[image: Image showing an example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to subclass View A (if it's not a custom view already) and override `pointInside:withEvent`.

Return `YES` if the specified point is inside one of View A's sub-views, or `NO` otherwise. When `pointInside:withEvent` returns `NO` the system will continue to try other views until it finds one that claims the point is inside it, then it will call `hitTest:withEvent` to see which inner-view to send the touches to (the default behaviour).

Comment: Im trying this but I never get a hit...  
 
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        UIView *result = [subview hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        if (result != nil)
        {
            return YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return NO;
}

Comment: I got it... my subviews are doing some hitTesting to because they are only responding to a label outside of the frame but you gave me what I needed, thank you... nice and simple... IOS is amazing, and so are you!

Comment: Cheers - don't call `hitTest` on the sub-views from `pointInside` though - call `pointInside` on the sub-views. It's like "Is this point in your view?" -> `NO` -> "Ok, forget it..." - "Is this point inside your view?" -> `YES` -> "Ok, which view is it in? (hit-test)". That is, `hitTest` should only get called if `pointInside` said `YES`.